# How to select a specific column with sqldf if no column name is given

Tags: r, sqldf, bigdata

I have a large file (data.txt, 35 GB) which has 3 columns.
Some example part of the file would look like the following:

```
...   ...    ...
5   701565  8679.56
8   1.16201e+006    3193.18
1   1.16173e+006    4457.85
14  1.16173e+006    4457.85
9   1.77942e+006    7208.73
4   1.78011e+006    8239.88
14  1.78019e+006    8195.57
9   2.00206e+006    8858.55
4   2.00199e+006    7924
...   ...    ...
```

I want to plot a histogram for the 3rd column when the values in the second column are between 0 and 50'000.

Then I want to do another histogram where the values of the first column are between 50'000 and 100'000. And so on, and so forth.

I don't know how to state the condition for the second column with the sqldf package since I don't have any column names?

It should probably be something like this:

> sql = "select * from file where 'column2' > 0 and 'column2' < 50000"

How can I select 'column2'?

Answer (score 1):

Since your data has no column names, read the data using `header = F`.

Then try the following example sql:

To read only those lines that satisfy 3rd col < 5000:

```
read.csv.sql(file = "test.txt", header = F, sep = " ", sql = "select * from file where v3<5000")
```

Result:

```
  V1      V2      V3
1  8 1162010 3193.18
2  1 1161730 4457.85
3 14 1161730 4457.85
```

Use v2 to filter by column 2.

Comment: I get the following error: Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: v3

Comment: How are you reading the data? Have you tried reading a few lines and see what the column names are?

Comment: I read a test file. Unfortunately, it gives me only one column. The column is called V1. Three numbers are in every row. E.g. Row 1 is: 9 43425.8 0

Comment: It seems that you may have a variable number of spaces as separators. `read.table` could handle this well, but it seems that `read.csv.sql` doesn't. I'll see what can I do.

Comment: I think that having multiple spaces as separator would lead to more than 3 columns. @Fabi are you sure your file is not tab-delimited? If it's the case use `sep = '\t'`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late, but I've had a similar problem and I've managed to solve it like this:

```
file <- data.frame(RN1 = runif(10), RN2 = 1:10, RN3 = letters[1:10])
sqldf("select Col2 from 
      (select NULL as Col1, NULL as Col2, NULL as Col3 where 1 = 0 UNION ALL select * from file)")
   Col2
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
10   10
```

Using `(select NULL as Col1, NULL as Col2, NULL as Col3 where 1 = 0 UNION ALL select * from file)` you can change the name of the columns in the query without having to change the names of the original data.frame, so I can write a column with the position regardless of whether the names change or are unknown.

**UPDATE:**

Another more efficient option is to obtain the name of the column and refer to it by its position.

```
sqldf(paste0("select ",
            names(sqldf("select * from file where 1 = 0")[2]),
            " from file"))
   RN2
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
```